# Caffe 1 Installation Error in Ubuntu17.04 - "undefined reference 'protobuf' and 'libcaffe.so'"

Tags: python, ubuntu, gcc, makefile, caffe

During installation (compiling) Caffe (the first version) with `make` on my Ubuntu 17.04, I receive the following error:

> .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadBytes(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*,
>   std::string*)'
>
> .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to
>   `google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString() const'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status Makefile:628: recipe for
>   target   '.build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin' failed
>
> make: *** [.build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin] Error 1

[image: error message during installation Caffe]

My computer specifications are as follows:

```
$ nvcc -V

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA
> Corporation Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017 Cuda compilation
> tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

The used gcc:

`$ sudo update-alternatives --config gcc`

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc).

  Selection    Path              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/gcc-4.9   10        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/g++-4.9   10        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/gcc-4.9   10        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/gcc-5     10        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/gcc-6     10        manual mode
```

OpenCV version:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion opencv
3.2.0
```

I already added the following regarding the [official website](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide) and modified the Makefile.config as:

```
 USE_CUDNN := 1
 OPENCV_VERSION := 3
 CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda-8.0
 BLAS := atlas
 PYTHON_INCLUDE :=  /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
 INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial
 LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
```

and Makefile as:

```
NVCCFLAGS += -D_FORCE_INLINES -ccbin=$(CXX) -Xcompiler -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS)

LIBRARIES += glog gflags protobuf leveldb snappy \
  lmdb boost_system boost_filesystem hdf5_hl hdf5 m \
  opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs opencv_videoio
```

I also tried `remove` and install again `protobuf` library by:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libprotoc10 -y
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libprotoc10 -y
$ sudo apt-get update
```

But the issue still remains there.

Comment: this error means that the caffe library is has method of communicating protobuf messages that are not available in your installed protobuf...in otherwords...your protobuf doesnt match the required version for caffe.. you need to build protobuf frource source as you are doing with caffe..checkout protobuf from github(for me with latest caffe is use 3.2.0) you can check which version by this command librotoc --version,anything less that 3.0.0 might not work

Comment: and i am afraid it might be for all these glog gflags protobuf leveldb snappy libraries,the thing is ubuntu official repo is always 1 version behind on most packages